# Can I repair Windows 7 startup files using an Ubuntu live CD/USB?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

Long story short, Windows 7 won't boot, and the "startup repair" routine just hangs. Not sure what is corrupted, if it's the MBR or what. Anyway, I was able to boot the live Ubuntu USB and move most of my personal data off the C: drive onto an external drive. If necessary I can reinstall Windows, but I'd rather try to repair it first if possible. Is there any way to diagnose/repair Windows boot problems through Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Windows 7 install/repair DVD/USB you can fix your Windows 7 installation.

1. Check that at least one primary partition is marked as active (the Windows 7 partition)
2. Run a Windows 7 StartUp Repair three consecutive times, rebooting after each run.
3. If this does not help, boot to the Windows 7 recovery console and run the following:

   ```
   bootsect /nt60 all /force /mbr
   bcdboot C:\Windows
   ```

   (Assuming C: is where Windows 7 is installed - if not change the drive letter accordingly.)